# Bicolored font (main color and background)

Tags: fonts, math-mode, color

I want to write some text on `tikzpicture` with bi-colored font: each character will be display in main color but each character will be doubled (like bold) with an other color.

The result I want to obtain is something like this:
[image]

Do you have any idea how can I obtain this kind of font (in text and math modes)?

**EDIT:** The package `contour` can be used to this but it seems to not working for some formula:

**MWE (not working):**

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}


\begin{document}
\contour{red}{$\vv{aa}$}$\vv{O_1O_2}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macro `\vv` breaks in a `\typeout` message, because `\vv` is not robust.
`\protect` helps:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\begin{document}
  \contour{red}{$\protect\vv{aa}$}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @karlkoeller Unstable internet connection :-(, but the answer is now updated.

Comment: I see, upvoted without the image, anyway...

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[fill=black]{\textcolor{red}{\contour{white}{This is some text}}};
  \node[text = white]at (0,-0.5){\contour{red}{This is some text}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes and for math mode? The documentation of this package says nothing about that (and I tried with no succes).